# Creating temp tables SQL Server 13.0.5426 with dynamic SQL doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to create a temp table using dynamic sql (MS SQL Server 13.0.5426).  This is a simplified example:

Using straight SQL works:

```
DROP TABLE #tmp_ts; -- will error, but ignored on the first execution
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ts INTO #tmp_ts;
SELECT * FROM #tmp_ts;
```

Creating it via dynamic SQL does not work.

```
DROP TABLE #tmp_ts; -- drop from previous test.
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ts INTO #tmp_ts';
SELECT * FROM #tmp_ts;
```

Output:

> (1 row affected)
>   Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 63
>   Invalid object name '#tmp_ts'.

My workaround is to not use a temp table, but I'm curious if anybody knows why this doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the scope of your temp table is to your current connection. When you `EXEC sp_executesql` it doesn't see your *local* temp table.

You could use a *global* temp table, which is denoted by using two #'s instead of one. I.E. `##tmp_ts`. However, with your small code sample there is no reason to use dynamic SQL. If you are simply trying to ensure a temp table doesn't exist before you insert into it, you can use the `OBJECT_ID` metadata function

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tmp_ts') is not null
drop table #tmp_ts

select
...
into #tmp_ts
...
```

Comment: The code was only simplified for StackExchange. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### This has never worked.

If you want to insert into a static temp table dynamically, you can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE #t(id INT);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases;';

INSERT #t ( id )
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT * FROM #t AS t;
```

If you need to build a temp table dynamically, see this Q&A:

- [Creating temporary table dynamically using condition](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/243371/32281)

Answer (score 0):

Given the next example:

```
CREATE TABLE Appointments
(
    fromDate datetime,
    toDate   datetime,
    appointmentMode int
);

INSERT INTO Appointments VALUES
('20190919 11:00:00', '20190919 11:45:00', 0),
('20190919 11:35:00', '20190919 12:00:00', 1),
('20190919 11:00:00', '20190919 12:00:00', 2);
```

You can either add the SELECT query to the dynamic query:

```
DECLARE @CMD NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @CMD = 'SELECT * INTO #T FROM Appointments; SELECT * FROM #T';

EXEC sp_executesql @CMD;
```

Or use a global temp table:

```
DECLARE @CMD2 NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @CMD2 = 'SELECT * INTO ##T2 FROM Appointments;';

EXEC sp_executesql @CMD2;

SELECT * FROM ##T2;
```

> ```
> fromDate            | toDate              | appointmentMode
> :------------------ | :------------------ | --------------:
> 19/09/2019 11:00:00 | 19/09/2019 11:45:00 |               0
> 19/09/2019 11:35:00 | 19/09/2019 12:00:00 |               1
> 19/09/2019 11:00:00 | 19/09/2019 12:00:00 |               2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9001e2303887a27236360f5d0204bd3a)*

Quoted from MS-Docs (bold is mine)

sp_executesql has the same behavior as EXECUTE with regard to batches, the scope of names, and database context. The Transact-SQL statement or batch in the sp_executesql @stmt parameter is not compiled until the sp_executesql statement is executed. The contents of @stmt are then compiled and executed as an execution plan separate from the execution plan of the batch that called sp_executesql. **The sp_executesql batch cannot reference variables declared in the batch that calls sp_executesql. Local cursors or variables in the sp_executesql batch are not visible to the batch that calls sp_executesql. Changes in database context last only to the end of the sp_executesql statement.**